# Tomcat server could not start after adding the .WAR file in webapp folder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, tomcat8

This error occured after we placed the .WAR file in the Tomcat's webapp folder. Then we tried going to the following link:

> http:// localhost:port/ProjectName/console

But a 404 error occurred. When we stopped the Tomcat server to restart it, we could not start the Tomcat server anymore. The following occured showed:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\b
in\Tomcat8.exe"
11-Sep-2014 19:02:44.775 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.init Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.31 using APR version 1
.4.8.
11-Sep-2014 19:02:44.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListen
er.init APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
random [true].
11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.201 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.
startElement Begin event threw exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoade
r
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRu
le.java:116)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1
184)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startEle
ment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.
emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.217 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.loa
d Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (215, 187) : org.apache.catalin
a.loader.VirtualWebappLoader
11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.243 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.
startElement Begin event threw exception
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoade
r
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRu
le.java:116)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1
184)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startEle
ment(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.
emptyElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
l.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(U
nknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown So
urce)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Un
known Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.p
arse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:613)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.258 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.loa
d Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (215, 187) : org.apache.catalin
a.loader.VirtualWebappLoader
11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.261 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.star
t Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

I also noticed this line of error:

```
11-Sep-2014 19:02:45.258 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.loa
d Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (215, 187) : org.apache.catalin
a.loader.VirtualWebappLoader
```

But when we checked if the file was missing, the file is still there.
[image: worklight-jee-library.jar]

Are we missing something?

Note:

- Worklight Server 6.2
- Apache Tomcat 8
- MySQL 5.6

Comment: ALWAYS mention your Worklight version and build number. Always.

Comment: Which instructions did you follow in order to deploy Worklight and the Worklight project, to Tomcat? Provide link.

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry about that, I've updated the information. I'm not sure where to find the build number for the worklight server... As for the link. Here it is: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_deploying_customization_war_file_to_application_server.html

Comment: In 6.2, the console URL is http://domain:port\worklightconsole

Answer (score 0):

The link you've provided in the comments points to Worklight 5.0.6, whereas you are using Worklight 6.2; You should use the correct instructions for your Worklight version. Here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_app_server.html?lang=en

Additionally, I think that this may just be an issue of using the wrong URL.

In Worklight 6.2 the Worklight Console URL is in fact `http://domain:port/worklightconsole`.
Try with this URL.